# Sylius: How to modify/customize app.js?

Tags: javascript, gulp, themes, sylius

I'm overriding the general theme in Sylius with my custom theme, which is working fine so far. I created a new theme in `app/themes/myCustomTheme` and am overwriting e.g. the twig templates in `/SyliusShopBundle/views/`.

Now I want to override the general `app.js` located in `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/private/js/`. E.g. instead on line 18:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion();
```

I would like to use a different selector to initialize the accordion:

```
$('.my-custom-accordion').accordion();
```

Assume this is the only change I want to do in the whole javascript code. What is the best and most efficient way to do this? I would like to have as minimum conflicts as possible when there is a Sylius version update and therefore touch as less files as possible. And of course, not have to rewrite the whole javascript functionality by myself.

I can think about different ways to do this, but I hope there's an even better one:

1. **Duplicate everything.** Copy all the `UiBundle` & `ShopBundle` javascript code to my theme and modify the necessary parts. Update the global gulpfile to no longer use the gulpfile in `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Gulpfile.js` and instead use the duplicated one `/myCustomTheme/SyliusShopBundle/Gulpfile.js`. Downside: duplicated code, javascript updates no longer possible.
2. **Add custom path to existing gulpfile.** Update the gulpfile in `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Gulpfile.js`, which means removing the line which includes the `app.js`: `vendorShopPath + 'Resources/private/js/**'` and instead reference all single files without the `app.js` AND reference to the customized `app.js` in my theme folder. Downside: Changes to the gulpfile are probably overwritten by the next update.

How do I efficiently modify/customize/extend the existing javascript code in Sylius?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for me creating a custom gulpfile in my bundle (AppBundle) and adding it to the global gulpfile in the same way of "admin" and "shop". After that you can include your custom app.js in the layout or whatever template. In my case I modified the Product/show.html.twig to add my custom .js:

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}

{% include '@SyliusUi/_javascripts.html.twig' with {'path': 'assets/app/js/app.js'} %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I understood you correctly, you're adding additional features with your custom app.js on top of the existing app.js, right? Your workflow seems to be a good solution if I want to add additional javascript, but what if I want to update/modify existing?

Comment: If you use the same function names as used in sylius' js, than you overwrite/replace those functions.

I am open for better ideas if anyone has.